# Visual Studio 2017 References vs Dependencies

Tags: reference, dependencies, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core solution in visual studio 2017 that is building against the .NET 4.7 framework.

In the main web application there is a dependencies menu that breaks down references into logical categories (Analyzers, Assemblies, NuGet, Projects).

[image: Dependencies Menu]

In the helper project it only has a references menu with everything jumbled inside. Is there a way to get the same treatment here as the web application got?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's based on the project file type. The older Full Framework project file gives you the References area, whereas the newer project files give you the Dependencies area. In other words, as long as it's a .NET Framework 4.7 project, there's nothing you can do about it.

That said, you can simply make it a .NET Standard 2.0 project, which does benefit from the new-style project file. Really, all your class libraries should be targeting .NET Standard, anyways, for greater interoperability.

Comment: How can you transform the project into this type without rebuilding it?

Comment: There's no easy way I know of. However, it's not all that complicated to simply create a new .NET Standard Class Library project, and just copy everything over to that. Once you're done, you can remove the original Full Framework library.

Comment: *Technically*, I think you should be able to literally switch out the project file XML with a reference copy from a new .NET Standard Class Library project and get most of the way if not all the way there. However, I'm not sure about that, and you may find yourself with weird errors after doing so.

Comment: When I create a new project in Visual Studio 2017, I dont see any Dependencies, I see References as usual. How did you get Dependencies displayed this way?

Comment: So Dependencies is the same as References. I can work with that

Answer (score 3):

No you can't get the same treatment.  It's because of the project type.  Different types of projects have different tooling and features.

In the old days before Asp.Net Core, projects generally just had the References area, and you could have references to other Visual Studio Projects or to Dlls (your own or System Dlls).

But Asp.Net Core provides a different interface for this sort of thing and provides better tooling support for NuGet for example.  For Asp.Net Core projects all this is organized below the Dependencies area.

But if you right click on Dependencies and select "Add Reference..." in your Asp.Net Core project, or if you right click on References and select "Add Reference..." in your .Net 4.7 Framework library you will see that in both cases you are presented with the same dialog.  So there is still some commonality in the UI ultimately used to add a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference causing this is the project "style". You have access to that menu on an SDK-style project, while the helper project is probably a traditional-style project.

NET Core and NET Standard projects are created as SDK-style projects by default, while NET Framework projects are usually created as traditional-style projects, but it is possible to migrate them. SDK-style project files are much cleaner than traditional-style ones.

[This open-source tool](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) automates the grist of the migration.
The following articles contain a guide: ([Part 1](http://hermit.no/moving-to-sdk-style-projects-and-package-references-in-visual-studio-part-1/), [part 2](http://hermit.no/moving-to-sdk-style-projects-and-package-references-in-visual-studio-part-2/))