# Dependencies vs References in VS2019 project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .net framework 4.7.2 project which i want to migrate to use Dependencies and not references.

I have tried clicking the migration options on the references: "Migrate packages.config to Package Reference", it migrates but stays "references" and does not switch to "dependencies".

I have seen some projects that managed to do it on a .net framework project, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432307/visual-studio-2017-references-vs-dependencies
Keep coding :)

Comment: Like the duplicate post linked, you can only achieve that by using the SDK based project format, not merely migrating to package references.