# Visual Studio References versus Dependencies, Assemblies, and Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, in a .NET Framework (not .NET Core) console application project, how do I add NuGet packages so that they show up in the "Packages" section of a "Dependencies" instead of just as "References" with other assemblies?  That is, I'd like to get this (which is from a Microsoft example app)...

[image]

... instead of this (which is what I have in my app after adding Newtonsoft.Json and MSAL using the NuGet package manager tool) ...

[image]

Notice, in my app, there is a "References" section but no "Dependencies" section, and the packages are mashed in with the other references.  The only thing I could find to try was to right-click on References then select the "Migrate packages.config to PackagesReference", which yielded this ...

*(StackOverflow bug?  When I try to add a third image, it shows some totally random image in a different language.  What the picture shows, though I can't get it to add, is the same "References" section except that the Json and MSAL references have a different icon.)*

... which is closer (the packages are now "references", I guess) but there is still no Dependencies section with partitioned Assemblies and Packages subsections.

Assuming the MS example is doing it "right" and that I am doing it "wrong", how do I get from where I am to where they are?

Answer (score 0):

Ah!  I think I found the answer at [Visual Studio 2017 References vs Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432307/visual-studio-2017-references-vs-dependencies).  It appears I need to use a different project type if I want the newer style project file.